# Inner observable not being updated

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

I am using rxjs to fetch registrants and their associated service and service image, however when the service get's updated it is not being reflected in my observable?

Can somebody figure out why, what am I doing wrong?

I have to keep writing stuff because stackoverflow won't let me post unless I write down redundant, superfluous information for the reader to read.

```
that._registrantsSubscription = that.userForumRegistrantService.getRegistrants(forum.uid, forum.forumId)
  .switchMap(registrants => {
    if (registrants && registrants.length > 0) {
      let observables = registrants.map(registrant => {
        let getService$ = that.userServiceService.getService(registrant.uid, registrant.serviceId);
        let getDefaultServiceImages$ = that.userServiceImageService.getDefaultServiceImages(registrant.uid, registrant.serviceId);

        return combineLatest(getService$, getDefaultServiceImages$)
          .switchMap(results => {
            const [service, defaultServiceImages] = results;

            if (service){
              if (defaultServiceImages && defaultServiceImages.length > 0)
                service.defaultServiceImage = of(defaultServiceImages[0]);
              else {
                let tempImage = {
                  tinyUrl: '../../../assets/defaultTiny.jpg',
                  name: 'No image'
                };
                service.defaultServiceImage = of(tempImage);
              }
              return of(service);
            }
            else return of(null);
          }
        );
      });
      return zip(...observables, (...results) => {
        return results.map((result, i) => {
          if (result)
            registrants[i].service = of(result);
          else
            registrants[i].service = of(null);
          return registrants[i];
        });
      });
    }
    else
      return of([]);
  })
  .subscribe(registrants => {
    that.registrants = of(registrants);
  }
);


public getRegistrants(parentUserId: string, forumId: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.afs.collection<any>(`users/${parentUserId}/forums/${forumId}/registrants`, ref => ref.orderBy('creationDate', 'desc')).valueChanges();
}


public getService (parentUserId: string, serviceId: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.afs.collection(`users/${parentUserId}/services`).doc(serviceId).valueChanges();
}

public getDefaultServiceImages (parentUserId: string, serviceId: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.afs.collection<any>(`users/${parentUserId}/services/${serviceId}/images`, ref => ref.where('default', '==', true).limit(1)).valueChanges();
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at using iif rather than switchMap returning multiple observables? https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/conditional/iif

Comment: Hi Adrian, I had a look at the iif, but I'm not sure how I should go about implementing it in my case?  Can you give me a quick example of what you mean and I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

I changed this bit of code:

```
return zip(...observables, (...results) => {
    return results.map((result, i) => {
      if (result)
        registrants[i].service = of(result);
      else
        registrants[i].service = of(null);
      return registrants[i];
    });
});
```

To this:

```
return combineLatest(...observables, (...results) => {
    return results.map((result, i) => {
      if (result)
        registrants[i].service = of(result);
      else
        registrants[i].service = of(null);
      return registrants[i];
    });
});
```

And now it works!

Not sure why, I still have to study up hard on rxjs.